# How to get the id of the newly created record in rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, suppose **model1** and **model2**. **model1** has many **model2**. **model2** **belongs** to **model1**. Save **model1** and **model2** at the same time.

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2s
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1
end

def create
   @mod1 = Model1.new(model1_params)
   id = Model1.last.id + 1
   @mod2 = Model2.new(model1_id: id)
   if @mod1.save && @mod2.save 
    redirect root_path
   else
    render 'edit'
   end
end
```

That solution is ok until I delete the last record of the model1. How can I get the last record of model1 before it created.

Comment: `id = Model1.last.id + 1`  -- Woah, woah, woah... Don't do that. That's a very bad idea, on multiple levels. What happens if two users perform a `create` action at the same time? (You'll get wrong associations caused by a race condition.) What happens if a record has been deleted? (You'll get the wrong ID, since the auto-incrementing index will have skipped a value.) What happens if this is the *first* instance of `Model1` to be created? (You'll get an undefined method error, since `Model1.last` is `nil`.)

Comment: How does the relation between `Model1` and `Model2` look like? Is it 1-1 or 1-n? Do they always come as a pair or can `Model1` exist without `Model2` (or vice-versa)? What is supposed to happen if a related record is deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most rails way to do this would be like this:

```
def create
  @mod1 = Model1.new(model1_params)
  @mod1.model2.build({args if you have them}) # this will only work if you have the relationship set up
  if @mod1.save
    # @mod1 is now saved along with model 2 who now has its ID
    # @mod1.id returns id, Model2.last returns model2 ID, Model2.last.model1_id returns Model1 ID
    #you can now delete model 1 if you wanted to, just make sure you don't have dependent destroy on in the model1.
    redirect root_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If your Model1 and Model2 subclass `ActiveRecord::Base`, then there is no need to set the id manually, in fact it's an anti-pattern.

Rails uses `ActiveRecord::Base` to model a schema-backed class. Suppose you have a database table called `model1s`. When you create a Model1 class like this

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Rails knows that the corresponding database table is `models1` (infers it from the name) and automatically generates an id once you save a new Model1 record. The id is usually an auto-incremented integer. This of course depends on the underlying database engine (MySQL, Postgresql, SQLite, ...)

So, in your example, you could just do

```
success = false
@mod1 = Model1.new(model1_params)
if @mod1.save
  @mod2 = Model2.new(model1_id: model1.id)
  success = true if @mod2.save
end
success ? redirect_to(root_path) : render('edit')
```

Some more tips. The `model1_id` attribute of Model2 looks like it's a foreign key. You should look into leveraging has_many/has_one/belongs_to associations to accomplish what you want in a more Rails idiomatic way

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :model2
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1
end

# Then you can do (one of the many options)
@mod1 = Model1.create(params)
@mod1.model2.create
```

It's useful to check the Rails guides on [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

I assumed you're using ActiveRecord, since you're using the `.last` and `.save` methods. I hope my instinct is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the id of record that haven't create.
The optimal answer for the solution is *save the @mod1 first. And get the id of its id.*

```
def create
  @mod1 = Model1.new(model1_params)

  if @mod1.save && Model2.create(model1_id: @mod1.id) 
    # @mod1 is now saved to the database. So @mod1.id will return id.
    redirect root_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: This is working code, but not very railsy. The rails way would be to use AR relations (`belongs_to`, in this case)

Comment: Unlike the original code, this one doesn't set `@mod2` which might be used in the `edit` view.

Comment: Furthermore, you should probably wrap everything in a transaction.

Comment: Also note that `create` (unlike `save`) always returns a _truthy_ value.