# How to get the id of newly created record in rails & associate the id with another model - Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm building a rails app connected to a react app. The rails app has four models. For arguments sake here, let's pretend it has two models: a sender & address. The sender belongs_to an address, and an address has_many senders. Therefore a sender has a foreign_key of address_id. When the sender registers for a new account, he creates an address as well. I'm trying to build something in my rails controller whereby when a new address is created it is associated with address_id column of the sender. I tried  building my own unique solution based on the solutions of [this rails thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296201/how-to-get-the-id-of-the-newly-created-record-in-rails-way) but I didn't have much success. I implemented the following in my address controller:

```html
class AddressesController < ActionController::API
    
    def show
        @address = Address.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def create 
        success = false
        address = Address.new(address_params)
        sender = @sender
        if address.save
            address_id = address.sender.build({address_id: address.id })
            success = true if !address_id.empty?
        else
            render json: { errors: address.errors.full_messages }, status: :bad_request
        end
        if success = true  
            render json: {status: 'address created successfully'}, status: :created 
        else  
            render('edit')
        end
    end 

    def address_params
        params.require(:address).permit(:streetname, :zipcode, :city, :country)
    end
end
```

And I'm getting this error in the terminal:

```html
  
NoMethodError (undefined method `sender' for #<Address:0x00007f93b2576050>
Did you mean?  senders
               senders=
               send):
  
app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

So I placed an attr_accessor in my senders controller:

```html
class SendersController < ApplicationController
attr_accessor :sender    
    def show
        @sender = Sender.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def create
        @sender = Sender.new(sender_params)
        if @sender.save 
          render json: {status: 'sender created successfully'}, status: :created
        else
          render json: { errors: sender.errors.full_messages }, status: :bad_request
        end
    end 
    
    def sender_params
        params.require(:sender).permit(:userid, :name, :email, :photourl, :address_id)
    end
end
```

I feel I'm over complicating things over here. So I really need help with this one. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'm adding these as comments because they're outside the scope of the question title, but there are several issues with your code:

Comment: 1) The error about 'sender' being undefined is referring to where you call `address.sender` - it's saying that the Address model has no `sender` method. The rest of the error text is important: it indicates that you _do_ have a `senders` method, so the relation in the Address model is probably `has_many :senders`, in which case you want `address.senders.build` instead.

Comment: 2) association.build returns the new record, so `address_id` will contain the sender record (not the address id) - it's not a great variable name

Comment: 3) `if success = true` is using an assignment (`=`) rather than a comparison (`==`) so you're _setting_ success to true, not checking it. Because it's a boolean, `if success` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

> NoMethodError (undefined method `sender' for)

First, the error triggered because you have `has_many` relation with `sender`, so it should be `senders` not `sender`

```
address.senders.build
```

> When the sender registers for a new account, he creates an address as
>   well. I'm trying to build something in my rails controller whereby
>   when a new address is created it is associated with address_id column
>   of the sender.

Second, your approach is wrong. You can make use of available methods for `belongs_to` association. For example, in your situation, you can call `@sender.build_address`

```
address = @sender.build_address(address_params)
```

> The `build_association` method returns a new object of the associated
>   type. This object will be instantiated from the passed attributes, and
>   the link through this **object's foreign key will be set**, but the
>   associated object will not yet be saved.

So, finally the create would look like below(after removing *unnecessary* code)

```
def create 
  address = @sender.build_address(address_params)

  if address.save
    render json: {status: 'address created successfully'}, status: :created
  else
    render json: { errors: address.errors.full_messages }, status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually set the id if you're creating a record via an association:

```
address.sender.build({address_id: address.id })
```

Can just be

```
address.sender.build
```

And rails will assign the id for you.